# Compiling with JDK 1.8 java: cannot access class file... class file not found

Tags: java, javac, java-6, java-8

Though the same code was getting to compiled successfully with JDK 1.6 version, after upgrading to JDK 1.8 it won't compile, saying `java cannot access ....class file ...as class file not found though it exists`.

I am compiling this in IntelliJ Idea 13 IDE, tried with both Rebuild option as well as configured ANT build - result is same.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
cannot access IDispatchRequest
class file for com.abc.xyz.orchestrator.dispatch.IDispatchRequest not found
1 error


Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1079)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:882)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:179)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
```

Comment: Check that the "missing" class is actually on the compile time classpath / buildpath.

Comment: Yes Stephen, it is in build path. If i switch back to JDK 1.6 no issues seen in compilation, happening when migrating to 1.8

Comment: are there any compile time issues reported by eclipse when you migrate to 1.8

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This issue is resolved now :). It's basically related to class path setup and only applicable for JDK 1.8.

For ex : If class 'A' has a reference to class B and class B is implementing an interface say 'C' then javac in JDK 1.8 requires both class B as well as Interface C on the class path where as prior to 1.8 only having class B on the class path was enough.

Please refer https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055048 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Build -> Rebuild Project worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when executing a function that was returning a class that i didn't had in classpath, but I just wanted to access his inner fields.
e.g:
`container.getContent().getField()`
I had to import the Content class to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant I had downloaded a corrupted jar I think.  Nuke ~/.m2/repository and try again...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the class that cannot be accessed was inside an external JAR.
The scenario was suitable with the accepted answer here.

I solved mine by adding the JAR as a dependency to the module that error was thrown.
Meaning if the error was thrown from class A, and class C was not accessed, I added the JAR containing class C as dependency to the pom.xml of module containing class A.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gradle to solve this problem.

Add "transitive = true" to the dependency. Just like this:

```
    compile('com.***.android:***sdk:1.0.2.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```